# Yii2 User как сделать единственную сессию пользователя?

Tags: yii2

Как добиться такого поведения модуля авторизации:
1. При авторизации пользователя в другом браузере разлогинивать этого пользователя во всех других браузерах.
2. Разлогинивать пользователя при смене его IP.

Сейчас использую модуль dektrium/yii2-user, но похоже, что подобной возможности нет и в дефолтовом модуле User Yii2.

P.S. Если я правильно понимаю, то в таблице user есть поле auth_key, при изменении которого пользователя должно принудительно разлогинить, но нигде не могу найти полноценный пример работы с данным полем.

Answer (score 0):

Слабо знаком c yii2.
Но чисто логически, нужно сравнивать на этапе проверки авторизации auth_key сессии с то что в базе.
Аналогично и ip адрес.
Если не совпадают, то разлогинить.